# Firestore storage request in the name of an application user (PHP)

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to authenticate our application user against Firebase/Firestore and then make a request to the storage as this user (i.e. not as the service account).

I know of two methods for the authentication:

### Simple HTTP Request

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$responee = $client->request(
  'POST',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=' . $key,
  [
    'headers' => [
      'content-type' => 'application/json',
      'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ],
    'body' => json_encode([
      'email' => $email,
      'password' => $password,
      'returnSecureToken' => true
    ]),
    'exceptions' => false
  ]
);
```

### Kreait SDK

```
$userRecord = $auth->verifyPassword($email, $password);
```

What I **don't know** is how to use this information to make a request to the storage.

### Google Cloud Firestore SDK

`StorageClient` accepts a config key `credentialsFetcher` but I don't know how to use it. It accepts any object that implements `FetchAuthTokenInterface`. I've toyed with those that exist, even tried implementing my own that just passes on the idToken from the *Simple HTTP Request* method. No luck.

```php
$credentialsFetcher = new myFetchAuthTokenImplementation($idToken);

$storage = new StorageClient([
  'credentialsFetcher' => $credentialsFetcher,
]);
$bucket = $storage->bucket('my_bucket');
$object = $bucket->object('file_backup.txt');

print $object->downloadAsString();
```

```php
use Google\Auth\FetchAuthTokenInterface;

class myFetchAuthTokenImplementation implements FetchAuthTokenInterface
{
  private $token;

  public function __construct(string $token)
  {
    $this->token = [
      'access_token' => $token,
    ];
  }

  public function fetchAuthToken(callable $httpHandler = null)
  {
    return $this->token;
  }

  public function getCacheKey()
  {
    return null;
  }

  public function getLastReceivedToken()
  {
    return $this->token;
  }
}
```

### Kreait SDK

It seems it can fetch information from storage but only using the service account. Not my application user.

```php
$firebaseFactory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');
$storage = $firebaseFactory->createStorage();
$imageUrl = $storage->getBucket()
    ->object('file_backup.txt')
```

I would need to re-initialize the `$firebaseFactory` with the application user record, something like this fictitious method `$firebaseFactory = (new Factory)->withApplicationUser($userRecord);`

Although I would like to use some SDK, any solution is fine, even with simple HTTP requests.

I would probably be able to implement this using the Google JavaScript SDK but I'd like to stick to PHP.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Kreait PHP SDK wraps the Google Cloud Storage REST API. If it does, it always accesses Storage with Administrative credentials, and there is no way to access it as a Firebase Authentication user account, nor to enforce the security rules for a specific user.

To access Cloud Storage as a Firebase Authentication user, you will have to authenticate client-side, and pass the resulting ID token to an SDK/API that enforces Firebase security rules for specific users. This means you'll have to use one of the [client-side Firebase SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) for accessing Cloud Storage, as there currently is no public REST API that exposes this functionality.

Comment: **To access Storage as ... user, you'll have to auth client-side**

How is this different from my _Simple HTTP Request_ method?

I tried using the JavaScript SDK and got a bunch of user related data back. I don't know though, how I can use it for my server-side calls.

Comment: **there currently is no public REST API that exposes this functionality**

The client-side SDKs use public REST API too, don't they?

You didn't mention _PHP Google Cloud Firestore SDK_ which uses GRPC ext. for API calls. Would you know to hook it up with the id token I got from calling the `verifyPassword` endpoint?

Comment: You seem to be mixing Cloud Storage and Cloud Firestore here. Note that both are different products, with quite different APIs. There is no public REST API from Firebase for Cloud Storage. While the Firebase SDKs may use HTTP calls (I never checked, but it make sense), that protocol is not documented. And there definitely is a REST API for Cloud Storage, this is meant for server-side access, and it does not enforce the security rules.

Comment: **Cloud Storage ... does not enforce the security rules**
My [Firebase Storage](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/pokusny-bea53/storage/pokusny-bea53.appspot.com/rules) console shows a Rules tab which makes me believe it can enforce security rules.

`rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
`

(I do admit that I am confused about the difference between Firebase and Firestore, so thank you for your patience).

Comment: The REST API for Cloud Storage is meant for server-side access to the files in your bucket, and it does not enforce the Firebase security security rules. I don't know how else to say this, so hope that somebody else can chime in.